# pointcloud_to_laserscan on dataset not with kinect

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am a newbie here and I was trying to use some visual slam, RGBD slam and all such
things until I have seen this pointcloud_to_laserscan. Now that, I want to see how good it is (by seeing the maps it produces and from odometry data computed from the laserscans) by testing it on the kinect datasets may be because I dont have kinect right now.
So, is there a way to do it with this pointcloud_laserscan package.
[Note: I am a complete newbie here so many things are pretty unclear to me at present, so I would appreciate if you can help me more elaborately.]
Thank you.
Vihari.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12730/pointcloud_to_laserscan-on-dataset-not-with-kinect/) by [Vihari](https://answers.ros.org/users/1594/vihari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No! I wasn't talking about simulation. Let me rephrase my question
if we see the launch file of pointcloud_to_laserscan

```
<launch>
  <!-- kinect and frame ids -->
  <include file="$(find openni_camera)/launch/openni_node.launch"/>

  <!-- openni_manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>

  <!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_camera">
    <param name="max_rate" value="2"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- fake laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_camera">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_frame"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>
</launch>`
```

which is taking input from kinect, now that I dont have kinect I want to migrate the point clouds that might have approached from kinect to those that are already there on my system.
This might be a trivial problem, but I am a complete newbie so I seek help.
Vihari

---

Originally posted by [Vihari](https://answers.ros.org/users/1594/vihari/) with karma: 16 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-24**:
Then you should just have to launch the launchfile and then play back the bagfile

**Comment by [Vihari](https://answers.ros.org/users/1594/vihari/) on 2012-01-24**:
I have them in  the bag file, i downloaded it from http://cvpr.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/download#freiburg1_xyz dataset

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-24**:
So you have saved point clouds on your computer? In what format are they saved?